# How to handle multibyte string in Python

Tags: python, string, multibyte, multibyte-functions

There are multibyte string functions in PHP to handle multibyte string (e.g:CJK script). For example, I want to count how many letters in a multi bytes string by using `len` function in python, but it return an inaccurate result (i.e number of bytes in this string)

```
japanese = "桜の花びらたち"
print japanese
print len(japanese)#return 21 instead of 7
```

Is there any package or function like mb_strlen in PHP?

Comment: For the completeness: This is no longer a problem in Python 3 with native Unicode support on all strings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [Unicode strings](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings):

```
# Encoding: UTF-8

japanese = u"桜の花びらたち"
print japanese
print len(japanese)
```

Note the `u` in front of the string.

To convert a bytestring into Unicode, use `decode`: `"桜の花びらたち".decode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 3):

Try converting it to `unicode` first:

```
print len(japanese.decode("utf-8"))
```

gives 7. You are working on the utf-8 encoded string, which indeed has 21 bytes.

Comment: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-6: ordinal not in range(128) :(

Comment: To remove the error:<br/>
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-6: ordinal not in range(128) :( <br/>

Add the following hashed line:<br/>

# Encoding: UTF-8<br/>