# Accessing Bangla (UTF-8) string by index in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8

I have a string in Bangla and I'm trying to access characters by index.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
bstr = "তরদজ"
print bstr # This line is working fine
for i in bstr:
    print i, # question marks are printed
```

I don't know why it isn't working.

Comment: This is thi same issue as in How to handle multibyte string in Python http://stackoverflow.com/q/8346608/802365

Comment: As your variable name indicate `bstr`is a byte string, not an unicode string https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn it into unicode:

```
>>> bstr = "তরদজ"
>>> for i in bstr.decode('utf-8'):
...     print i
... 
ত
র
দ
জ
```

Comment: An alternative way instead of explicitly calling `decode` is to assign an unicode string literal to `bstr` by prepending the string literal with an `u`. -> `bstr = u"তরদজ"`